# How do they do this semi-transparent overlay effect in javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

If you navigate to http://learn.knockoutjs.com/ you get a 'welcome' style screen which is a semi-transparent overlay that introduces users to the screen elements.  It's nifty.

It looks a little like the jquery plugin BlockUI, but I think it's something a bit more fancy than that.  Fancybox comes close, but seems to only offer a single centre element.  Viewing source didn't help me much, I'm not a JS expert by any means.

Does anyone know how this is done or how to do something similar on a page?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Steve used: http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/ for the message boxes on the tutorial pages.

You might like this post that describes the open source tools that he used in creating learn.knockoutjs.com:  http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/07/22/review-open-source-components-used-in-learnknockoutjs/

Comment: Thanks for that.  Exactly answers my question (though in the blog he notes he didn't like that plugin and regrets using it!)  Good to know though.  Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Have a quick look at the example below:

http://jsfiddle.net/2q7xT/

**Explanation:**

This is probably not the best implementation but the idea is there. First you will be needing a `<div>` which you will fill with either a semi-transparent black image:

```
background: url(semi-transparent-image.png) repeat;
```

I used the RGBA technique but it's not supported by all browsers.

The second solution is to fill the div with a black color such as:

```
background-color: #000;
```

and then use the Cross-browser `opacity` css attribute to reduce the opacity:

```
/* IE 8 */
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";

/* IE 5-7 */
filter: alpha(opacity=50);

/* Netscape */
-moz-opacity: 0.5;

/* Safari 1.x */
-khtml-opacity: 0.5;

/* Good browsers */
opacity: 0.5;
```

The most important part is that this div should have `position: fixed;` and a `z-index` lower than the `z-index` of the element above it.

Answer (score 4):

That's called a lightbox, or, a modal box. There are several cool jQuery lightbox plugins. Here are a few:

1. [FancyBox](http://fancybox.net)
2. [ColorBox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/)
3. [LightView](http://www.nickstakenburg.com/projects/lightview/)

**I suggest FancyBox or ColorBox for what you're trying to do. FancyBox is my favorite.**

Here are the top 10 jQuery modalbox plugins: [Top 10 jQuery Modal Box Plugins](http://web.enavu.com/tutorials/top-10-jquery-modal-box-plugins/)

Note: Using only CSS for a dialog (another answer has suggested doing it that way) isn't that good, as you will not be able to make cool fading transitions and you wont be able to make it close with a button or link.

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: Good points.  I did come across some of those but the 'whole page overlay with multiple sections' weren't obvious among the examples.  Some finagling will be needed :0)  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

yeah, it kind of looks like a jquery ui dialog plugin. I've actually been looking into creating something similar and it's my understanding that those ui dialogs are pretty customizable. Here's a basic tutorial I found on youtube http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b16V25eNyJY. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Glinkot.
If you look at the web pages source code it gives you a div like this:

```
<div id="seeThru" style="opacity: .75; height: 100%; width: 100%"></div>
```

from there you can just overlay anchors or whatever else

Comment: If you copy that div alone into a HTML document (and you add the missing double quotes), nothing happens.